# How to noramilze a BatchDataset and use it in a model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset, training-data

I have a problem with normalizing a BatchDataset. I tried a lot of different ways but I always get some Errors e.g. ..not callable when I want to see if it worked out.

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(training_folder,
                                                               image_size=(256, 256),
                                                              label_mode="binary")                                                      
valid_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(validation_folder,
                                                               image_size=(256, 256),
                                                              label_mode="binary")
```

So I get this dataset shape.

```
<BatchDataset shapes: ((None, 256, 256, 3), (None, 1)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32)>
```

How can I normalize this dataset?

Futhermore my model.fit does not work but I can not find the problem.

```
num_classes = 2
input_shape = (224, 224, 3)

model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=input_shape),
        layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dropout(0.5),
        layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax"),
    ]
)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_ds, 
          epochs=5,
          batch_size=128,
          validation_data = valid_ds)
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to SO Svenson! Two suggestions for helping you get answers: 1) Please ask a single question in your post -- you currently have two questions combined here. 2) Please post the error that you receiving.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `map`:

```
train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (tf.divide(x, 255), y))
```

Also I suggest you use 1 neuron in your final layer with `"sigmoid"` activation

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the image dimensions in image data set as 256 by 256 but in your model you specify an input shape of 224 by 224. To rescale the image inputs put this directly after the input layer

```
tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1/255)
```